# Extend tv coaxial cable (uk)

Tags: television, coaxial-cable

I recently moved into a property and the TV aerial socket is in a different room from where we want it.

Currently I am running a 15m coaxial cable through the house to the tv in a different room.

After researching, I have bought 25m of external coaxial cable which I plan connect to the existing aerial cable outside and run it around the house to the other room.

Before I start drilling I decided to test the cable to see if carries the signal ok.

This is where I have a problem.  I can't seem to get a signal when connecting it to the old coaxial cable.

To test, I took a foot of the new cable and tested it and it worked, hence why I wonder if the cable is too long.

After testing , I can only assume that the 25m is too long and the signal is too weak.
Does this sound right?

The only thing I can't understand is that I am already using a 15m cable and that the carries the signal without a problem.  Would an extra 10m really cause a problem?

Thanks

Comment: 15 plus 25 might cause signal weakling, but just 25 should not.  How are you combining cables or are you?  Single piece coax is better than having connectors.  Might need a pre-amp/booster.

Comment: Make sure your connectors are making contact.  Check the continuity of the cable, pin to pin and base to base  and no continuity base to pin.

Comment: The cables are being connected with f-connectors and a f-coupler

Answer (score 1):

Every metre of cable will lose a bit of signal.  Every join will lose a bit of signal.  If it's the wrong cable, or a bad joint, it will lose a bit more.

The trouble with digital TV is that it works or it doesn't.  If the signal drops too low, you get nothing.  You may only get some stations, or none at all.

So check that your joints are correct and that it's actually TV aerial cable.  Then think if there's an alternative route from the aerial to the TV that requires less cable.

But you might end up needing a TV aerial amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure - how are you making the connection? Crimped F connectors and barrels, or something else? Do you have some experience in using an F-connector crimper, or that all new to you? They are not hard, but it's possible to make mistakes.

What types of coax are involved?

Coax has nominal impedance - a mis-matched (so, 50Ω connected to a 75Ω) chunk a foot long might work while a mis-matched chunk 25m long might not. Over here 75Ω (75 Ohm) cable is usual for TV, 50Ω is common for other purposes, and there are many others (less commonly seen in consumer uses.)

*I'd suspect that might actually be similar, but I never know for sure in cross-pond issues where different standards may have been chosen. A brief search appears to indicate concurrence on this point, though.*

Likewise, each type has a characteristic signal loss per length, which generally tends towards smaller diameter, easier to handle cables have more loss, and larger diameter cables that don't bend as easily have less loss. So, RG-59 is more flexible and more lossy than RG-6 is more flexible and more lossy than RG-11, for three common 75Ω "TV coax" types.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies.

The cable is being connected via f-connectors but they aren't crimped.  They are screwed on.  They are then connected with inline f-coupler.

This is the cable https://www.screwfix.com/p/time-rg6-black-1-core-round-coaxial-cable-25m-drum/667jy

Thanks